# Setting a legend in the center of a circular barplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this tutorial to create a circular barplot: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/295-basic-circular-barplot.html

I want to create a legend in the middle of the barplot, where the white area is. However, so far i have only been able to add text in the middle. If i want to draw a small cube with the colour, it wraps itself around and i don't know how it uses the coordinates (i tried x = 0, y = 0 which gives the result below, they are always curved).

These are the two lines that i added:

```
geom_tile(aes(x = 1, y = 0, colour = "#EB5500"), width = 100, height = 100, inherit.aes = F) +
geom_text(x = 0, aes(y = -100, label = "test"), size = 4)
```

So that the full code now looks like this:

```
# Clear workspace 
rm(list = ls())

# Libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  id=seq(1,60),
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar

  # This add the bars with a blue color
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("blue", 0.3)) +

  # Limits of the plot = very important. The negative value controls the size of the inner circle, the positive one is useful to add size over each bar
  ylim(-100,120) +

  # Custom the theme: no axis title and no cartesian grid
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-2,4), "cm")     # This remove unnecessary margin around plot
  ) +

  # This makes the coordinate polar instead of cartesian.
  coord_polar(start = 0) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = 1, y = 0, colour = "#EB5500"), width = 100, height = 100, inherit.aes = F) +
  geom_text(x = 0, aes(y = -100, label = "test"), size = 4)

p
```

But this gives me an image that looks like this: [image]

It seems that ggplot automatically adds a legend based on the grid that I added. That legend needs to be in the center, and it should be a legend for the blue bar chart instead of the grid. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the legend supposed to show?

Comment: The mapping of the bars. Your answer was perfect. I didn't understand how legend.position() worked before, I thought I had to enter coordinates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't really get about your question is what is supposed to be in the legend. The idea of legends is that they explain a mapping (something inside `aes()`) so you usually want to have that in your data already:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  id=seq(1,60),
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T),
  colour = "test1" # added to have something to map to
)
```

Now you can map the `fill` aesthetic to the new column. To move the legend to the center you have to add `legend.position = c(0.5, 0.5)` to your `theme`.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill = colour)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    legend.position = c(0.5, 0.5), # move legend to the center
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-2,4), "cm")     # This remove unnecessary margin around plot
  ) +
  coord_polar(start = 0)

p
```

[image]

I chose `test1` to show that anything can go into the data. To change the colour you have to define a manual (or other) scale:

```
p +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha("blue", 0.3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`theme(legend.position = c(.5, .5))` center the legend to the plot.